# Java Null Pointer

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Does anyone know why I am getting a null pointer error when I call the getResultSet() method from MyServ2 class

here is my DBClass (imports etc omitted)

```
public DBClass(){

    }

public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
        String db_userid, String db_password)
{

        try
        {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

        return conn;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;
            }
}



public ResultSet getResultSet(String query){

    try{
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    result = stmt.executeQuery(query);  

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return result;

}



}
```

and this is my MyServ2 class

```
public class MyServ2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private DBClass db;

    public MyServ2() {
        super();
        db = new DBClass();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        ResultSet rs = db.getResultSet("Select * from ....ect");
        try {
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1).toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not calling dbConnect method  i think. therefore you are not connected to db and your query returns null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling `db.dbConnect()`, so `db.conn` will be null.